# Meteor. Back Button not working in Chrome for iPhone

Tags: iphone, google-chrome, meteor

I have a fairly simple Meteor app.
There's a very small database, no complicated Javascript - a small and simple Meteor app. 
I use Iron Router.

Yet the back button does virtually nothing in Chrome for Iphone 5 and for Iphone 6. Works perfectly on desktop Chrome and on Ipad Chrome, also works beautifully on Iphone in Safari.

It's hard to see what the back button is doing, it just blocks.

```
Android browser OK
Desktop Chrome OK
Ipad Chrome OK
IPhone 5 Safari OK
IPhone 6 Safari OK
IPhone 5 Chrome KO...
IPhone 6 Chrome KO...
```

I'm not sure where to start to solve the problem, so I was wondering if anybody else has had a similar problem.

Any help gratefully received.

Comment: Seconding.  It does not work for me in my Meteor application on Android using the chrome browser